# kotlin companion object constructor

Tags: kotlin

I'm studying Kotlin with design patterns.

So I write a singleton pattern.

Below code is test code.
first show that instance is only one.
second show that there is no public constructor.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertSame
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class TestSimpleSingleton {
    @Test
    fun testCreateSingleton() {
        val s = Singleton.Instance()
        val s2 = Singleton.Instance()
        assertSame(s, s2)
    }

    @Test
    fun testNoPublicConstructors() {
        val singleton = Class.forName("Singleton")
        val constructors = singleton.constructors
        assertEquals(0, constructors.size) // public constructor = 0
    }
}
```

if i use object to implement singleton the test is work well.(val s = Singleton)

```
object Singleton
```

but i use a companion object it doesn't work.

```
class Singleton private constructor(){
  companion object {
    private var theInstance: Singleton? = null
    fun Instance(): Singleton {
      if (theInstance == null)
        theInstance = Singleton()
      return theInstance as Singleton
    }
  }
}
```

I write private constructor so I thought it also didn't have any public constructor.
but the second test shows that it has one public constructor.

Why did it happen like this?

Comment: Looking at the bytecode, Kotlin appears to be generating a public synthetic constructor that takes an argument of type [`DefaultConstructorMarker`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/92d200e093c693b3c06e53a39e0b0973b84c7ec5/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/jvm/internal/DefaultConstructorMarker.java). This is normally used when you have a constructor that takes optional arguments (so Kotlin generates several overloads and marks the "original" one with that marker class). I have no earthly idea why Kotlin is doing it in *your* case though.